# LstListing keeps adding whitespaces when a - is used

Tags: bash, lstdefinestyle

So I want to have some nice listings for a manual I'm writing.
The instructions should be copied to the ubuntu terminal in which a bunch of them can be ran after each other.

I fixed that, but now I've run into the problem that lstlisting keeps adding weird white spaces, as you can see in the image below.

[image]

This is my lstdefinestyle:

```
\lstdefinestyle{ubuntuterminal}{
    language=bash,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    escapeinside={*@}{@*},
    autogobble=true,
    keywords={sudo},
    showstringspaces=false,
    keywordstyle=\color[RGB]{94 109 45},%\color[RGB]{0 151 189},
    keywords=[2]{apt-get},% define keywords 
    keywordstyle=[2]{\color[RGB]{0 151 189}},
    morecomment=[l]{//},
    breaklines=true;
    breakatwhitespace = true,
    breakindent       = 0pt,
    postbreak=\raisebox{-.2ex}[0ex][0ex]{\color{black}\large\ensuremath{\hookrightarrow\space}},
    tabsize=4,
    numbers=left,
    numbersep=5pt,
    columns=fullflexible
    numberstyle=\numberwithprompt,
}
```

And this is how I call it in the latex code:

```
Make sure the pc is fully up to date.
\begin{lstlisting}[style=ubuntuterminal]
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get upgrade
\end{lstlisting}
```

Please help me fix this :)

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, this might sound rather stupid, answering my own question after a couple of minutes, but I found the problem.

In my lstdefinestyle I forgot to end the columns= line with a , which resulted in this line doing absolutely nothing.
So for anyone who wants to use this:

```
\lstdefinestyle{ubuntuterminal}{
    language=bash,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    escapeinside={*@}{@*},
    autogobble=true,
    keywords={sudo},
    showstringspaces=false,
    keywordstyle=\color[RGB]{94 109 45},%\color[RGB]{0 151 189},
    keywords=[2]{apt-get},% define keywords 
    keywordstyle=[2]{\color[RGB]{0 151 189}},
    morecomment=[l]{//},
    breaklines=true;
    breakatwhitespace = true,
    breakindent       = 0pt,
    postbreak=\raisebox{-.2ex}[0ex][0ex]{\color{black}\large\ensuremath{\hookrightarrow\space}},
    tabsize=4,
    numbers=left,
    numbersep=5pt,
    columns=fullflexible,
    numberstyle=\numberwithprompt,
}
```

Comment: Nothing is stupid about finding own errors.